# Simulate native click

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I need to trigger the click event on a link and then, if none of the listeners prevented the default, change the location.

This is what I've got so far:

```
var $el = $('a#my_special_link');
var onClick = $el.attr('onclick');

// Hack to capture the event object
var ev_reference;
var ev_capture = function(ev) { ev_reference = ev; }
$el.bind('click', ev_capture);

// Don't leave out the onClick handler
if ( typeof onClick == 'function' )
    $el.bind('click', onClick);

$el.trigger('click');

// Clean up
$el.unbind('click', ev_capture);
if ( typeof onClick == 'function' )
    $el.unbind('click', onClick);

// Redirect if necessary
if ( ! ev_reference.isDefaultPrevented() )
  window.location = $el.attr('href');
```

Any suggestions for improvement are welcome.

**PS:** Yes, it's just how a regular link would work, except you can do some other processing in between.

**PPS:** No, just doing `$el.trigger('click');` will *not* change the location.

Answer (score 4):

`enter code here`To extract my notes to others posts: (another way to say same basic stuff)

```
      <a href="somewhere" id="mylink">MyLink</a> 
        <script>jQuery('#mylink').click(function(){
            // do whatever I want here, then redirect
             window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
        });
        function doClick(){
            jQuery('#mylink').trigger('click'); 
        };
        // trigger the redirect now
        doClick();
        </script>
```

EDIT1:@ comments:

If the "other" you describe returns false, you at that point, terminate the callback with the false - so you are correct but has nothing to do with this handler.  Which ever one hits first executes, and the other never does return, and this one redirects prior to the other one hitting the log if it executes first.

In order to put your log in, you put that where I have my

```
 "// do whatever I want here, then redirect"
```

comment
To remove the other event, then bind with this one only:

```
   <a href="somewhere" id="mylink">MyLink</a> 
        <script>jQuery('#mylink').unbind('click').bind('click', function(){
            // do whatever I want here, then redirect
             window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
        });
        function doClick(){
            jQuery('#mylink').trigger('click'); 
        };
        // trigger the redirect now
        doClick();
```

Comment: That won't work with another handler. For example:

    jQuery('#mylink').click(function(){
        console.log('another handler');

        return false;
    });

Comment: The problem is that I don't have control over the other handlers. I just have to make sure they are executed and then decide if I should redirect or not.

Comment: The unbind can get you control before the other takes place, but of course if a link executes to another site, you will NOT have the choice as the train will have left the station and the page will be replaced.

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.jquery.com/Events/trigger#eventdata

```
$('a#my_special_link').trigger("click");
```

Comment: This will not redirect or anything.  It only executes the event handler.

Comment: Exactly. I already trigger the event handlers. I need the redirecting part.

Answer (score 0):

> "if none of the listeners prevented the
>   default, change the location."

Sounds exactly how a normal link behaves...?

Anyway, if you are trying to look for "return false", it will not be found using `isDefaultPrevented()`, which only will return true if `preventDefault()` is called from the same event object. In this example, I'm sending the event object to `whatever()` and if that function sets `preventDefault()`, the window will relocate anyway (is that what you need...?)

```
$('a#my_special_link').bind('click', function(e) {
  whatever(e);
  if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
    window.location = $(e.target).attr('href');
  }
});
```

Comment: Any handler - except onClick="" - that either returns false or calls ev.preventDefault() will cause isDefaultPrevented() to return true, so that's not an issue.

The problem is that I'm not the one writing the onClick="" attribute. I just have to handle it.

Comment: OK, so how do you want to handle it? it sounds like you can simply trigger the click using trigger('click'), and then let the browser redirect naturally if no eventHandler prevented the default.

Comment: For security reasons, I presume, the browser will _not_ redirect if you simply trigger the click event.

Comment: trigger the the click, if you are on the SAME page (*or same site) will redirect to the default if that is what the link does you trigger the click on - just like having a link to another site and manually clicking it.

Comment: Try this: <a href="etc">link</a> <script>jQuery('a').click();</script> and see what happens. (Hint: nothing)

Comment: Yours adds the EVENT HANDLER (DO THIS WHEN I CLICK) not the event TRIGGER (DO the event now) make it <a href="somewhere" id="mylink">MyLink</a>

<script>
jQuery('#mylink').trigger('click');
</script>

Comment: NOTE: my "somewhere" should be a valid http ref to somewhere you want to go like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786377/jquery-simulate-native-click

Comment: .click() - with no arguments - is shorthand for .trigger('click'). Try it both ways, if you're not convinced.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you have an `a` element that you don't control, which has an `onclick` attribute that returns `false`. Returning `false` from an onclick handler prevents a click on the link from taking you to the linked page. And you don't want that.

You could store the `onclick` handler function and then remove it from the link element:

```
var $a = $('#my_special_link'); 
var onclickHandler = $a.attr('onclick');
$a.removeAttr('onclick');
```

Then cal the stored handler function in your custom click handler:

```
$a.click(function() {
    // ...
    onclickHandler();
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Yes, I'm already doing that with $el.bind('click', onClick); Don't know if I should remove the onclick attribute, though.