# How to "trigger" a click event on a specific anchor element with Javascript? preferably with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-click-event

What I want to do is issue a click event, preferably with jQuery, on an anchor element, causing the browser to follow that link. I know that my anchor selectors are correct, as they are returning 1 from .length.

Here's what I've tried:

```
$('#awesomeLink').click();
```

But it won't follow the link.

How am I doing it wrong?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just parse the url and send the user to that link location?

```
var url = $('#awesomeLink').attr('href');
window.location.href = url;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `$('#awesomeLink').trigger("click");`

Comment: Maybe I didn't read enough. I thought the question was how to trigger the even. Navigating to the link without triggering the event, however, would be Tejs's recipe spot on.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to click the link directly, just tell the browser to load a different page:

```
window.location = "my_link's_URL";
```

This question is similar to [how-do-i-automatically-click-a-link-with-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902713/how-do-i-automatically-click-a-link-with-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

If you are just wanting to change the browser location try:

```
window.location.href = $('#awesomeLink').attr('href');
```

Otherwise if you are needing a bit more, then [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786377/jquery-simulate-native-click) might help (as might the other questions about native clicking).

Comment: Apparently I type very slowly.